# How to move or copy list of files referenced in a csv file to a new folder

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'd like to write a shell script (OSX) which copies files listed in a csv file to a particular directory. I need to strip quotes from each line in the csv file.

My attempt

```
for i in $(cat myfile.csv)
  temp="${$i%\"}"
  temp="${temp#\"}"

do
  cp foldername/$temp foldername/subfoldername
done
```

I get this error:

```
./mfcsv.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `temp="${$i%\"}"'
./mfcsv.sh: line 2: `  temp="${$i%\"}"'
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of your csv file?

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 errors:

1. Wrong loop syntax, `do` should be at 2nd line
2. bad substitution syntax, no dollar sign before `i` needed

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(cat myfile.csv)
do
  temp="${i%\"}"
  temp="${temp#\"}"

  cp foldername/$temp foldername/subfoldername
done
```

but, it will fail if you have spaces in filenames. Script below will work also with spaces:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read i;
do
  temp="${i%\"}"
  temp="${temp#\"}"

  cp "foldername/$temp" "foldername/subfoldername"
done < myfile.csv
```

Comment: I've used the 2nd script in the past and it works great. I'm now facing a slightly different use case where the file extension is unknown i.e. searching for «12345» should find «12345.jpg» or «12345.jpeg» or «12345.psd». Is there an easy way to adapt the above script ?

Answer (score 2):

Put the `do` after the parameters expansions, not before. And leave out the $sign within the expansion and use double quotes around the expansions except when assigning to a variable. For example

```
while read file
do
  temp=${file%\"}
  temp=${temp#\"}
  cp "foldername/$temp" "foldername/subfoldername"
done < myfile.csv
```

Comment: thanks. In your example is 'file' received as a command line argument or should it be replaced with the filename?

Comment: @codecowboy You're welcome. `file` is a variable name, you could also use `i` and then `temp=${i%\"}`